# jQuery doesn't work in a dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with my web application. I've created a tchat in Ajax and I want it to be loaded when I click on a button. It works, but the dynamic data loaded doesn't support jQuery.

When I click on the button, I dynamically change the content of a div, initially empty. But on this finder (which open) I have a link which should load smileys simply in changing the height of the div, which is initially at 0 px.

I've done tests, and when I click on the button, the height is good changed, but nothing appear on the screen.

Here is a screenshot of my chat:

[image]

When I click on the smiley, I should see that:

[image]

But nothing happened.

Here is the code that works fine because the height is changed (I've tested it) :

```
var elm = window.document.getElementById('myCGU_Appear-1');
if (elm.style.height == "0px")  {
    elm.style.height = "100px";
    elm.style.overflow = "auto";
    window.document.getElementById('appear_emoticon-1').src = "/assets/images/emoticons/my_small_emoticons_000.png";
} else {
    elm.style.height = "0px";
    window.document.getElementById('appear_emoticon-1').src = "/assets/images/emoticons/my_small_emoticons_01.png";
}
```

I think I've done a mistake somewhere because yesterday the code worked fine...

Here is the code that load the tchat :

```
$.ajax({
        url:"/scripts/ajax/load_tchat.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: "method_call=open",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);

            if(data.tchat_operation == 'open') {

                // load datas
                $("#frameChat").html(data.tchat_content);

                // open the tchat
                frameChat.classList.remove("Espace-Chat-Ferme");
                frameChat.classList.add("Espace-Chat");

            }
        },
        error: function(resultat, statut, erreur){
            console.log(resultat);
            console.log(erreur);
        }
    });
```

And here is the JSON code that is send to me and that I've on my div :

```
> this.tchat_content
< "
[...]

    <div style=\"position: absolute; bottom: 5px; width:280px; class=\"myBackgroundGreyLight\">
        <div class=\"section group\">
            <div class=\"col span_1_of_1\"><div id=\"myCGU_Appear-1\" name=\"myCGU_Appear-1\" style=\"height:0px;margin-bottom:2%;-webkit-transition:all 0.2s ease-in;transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;overflow: hidden;display:block;\" class=\"myBackgroundGreyLight\">All emoticons</div>

    <a href=\"#\" onclick=\"My_CGU_Appear2(-1,5000)\" class= \"button scrolly\" >
        <img id=\"appear_emoticon-1\"  src=\"/assets/images/emoticons/my_small_emoticons_01.png\" width=\"6%\">
    </a><div class=\"fileUpload\">  
                <input type=\"file\" accept=\"image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg, image/jpg\" id=\"imgInp-1\" />
            </div>

    <div>
        <a href=\"#ouvre_photo\" onclick=\"AddImageInInput2(this,-1);\">
            <img id=\"blah-1\" src=\"\" alt=\"\" />
        </a>
    </div><div contentEditable=\"true\" class=\"contact_message\" id=\"txt_comments-1\" onkeyup=\"ia_content_analysis(-1, event,2);\" style=\"background-color:white;max-height:125px;overflow-y:auto;overflow-x:hidden;min-height: 50px;\"></div>

<div id=\"test-1\" style=\"float:right;\">
    <h4>&nbsp;</h4>
</div>

<div id=\"callback_-1\" style=\"font-size:11px;margin-top:10px;\"></div>

<div style=\"clear:both; display:block; height:10px;\"></div>

<div style=\"display:inline-block;width:100%;\">
    <a style=\"display:inline-block;background-color:#bf0e07;float:right;border-radius:4px;padding:5px;cursor:pointer;width:50px;text-align:center;font-size:12px;color:white;\" rel=\"-1\" class=\"publish_message\">Publier</a>
</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src=\"/assets/javascript/jquery.min.js\"></script>
    <script src=\"/assets/javascript/My_JSFunctions.js\"></script>
    <script src=\"/assets/javascript/ajax.js\"></script>"
```

Thanks if you can help me or show me the right way :)

Comment: So what part of it is broken? You talk about jQuery but you don't show any. Can you show the broken code?

Comment: @putvande : I've edited my first message. But my code works when it is not called in dynamic content, so it is strange...

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set any event handler on your emoticon-button. After loading HTML data via ajax you have to reinitialize all your event handlers previously set on your elements if you had set them via ID. So instead of reinitializing all the time you could try:

```
$(document).on('click', '#yourButtonId', function() { /* my logic */ });
```

instead of assigning the event handler directly on the dynamic content. I hope I got you right. Else providing a JSFiddle would help.

Comment: Thanks, it works! But now I have an other problem, my tchat doesn't display when I'm on Safari browser, but it works perfectly on Chrome. What can explain that?

Comment: Please provide a JSFiddle for that. Try to minimize your code to the absolute minimum, at which your error still occurs. Then paste the code to JSFiddle and open a new question. Chrome and Safari, despite using a similar rendering engine (webkit derivate), behave differently in JavaScript, since Chrome currently supports more ECMAScript 6 features.